# Default Entitlement process

Tags: entitlements

I need to automate the entitlement process assignment.
I could not find a declarative why to do that?
How can I automatically assign an Entitlement process to a case based on its priority?

Answer (score 1):

Entitlements don't automatically apply to cases.

[image: Read this snipped from the entitlement management]

[This is the link to the Entitlement management PDF refer page 16](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_entitlements_implementation_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. Write a trigger on insert or update of case